# Spring Domains or EJB3 Entities?

Tags: java, spring, entity, spring-data

I have implemented a Data Access Layer by mean of Spring-Data's facilities. At the moment I use the Hibernate Tools (in Eclipse) to generate the annotated EJB3 Entities of the tables of my DB. 
Clearly the fetched data should flow through my application layers so I need to implement the Domain (as Spring calls it) part of the application. Theoretically the Domain should be a agnostic-to-the-implementation POJO, meaning it should not contain Entity's annotations.

Keeping in mind that the Entity is unavoidable to make things work, what is the usual behaviour? Should I create a Domain class library which simply mirrors the Entity data and is only a POJO (with the help of [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/gettingstarted.html) to make the copy part) or should I use the Entity even outside the DAL (thus losing the Domain's agnostic-to-the-implementation attitude)?

Thank you in advance

Giulio

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you could always use XML mapping for the domain to tie it with the implementation of the persistence provider. A tutorial can be seen here http://java.dzone.com/articles/persisting-entity-classes

Comment: Hi geoand, thank you for you comment.
The problem is that I'm bound to QueryDSL (www.querydsl.com) for the query part and Query DSL needs the Entity to be in the annotations form...

Comment: Moreover, I must use plugins and automatic agents to generate Entities (it's a project restriction) and the proposed approach would require my intervention every time I edit the table structure